# How to add new page in pim section in oragehrm

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, orangehrm

How to add new page  and show simple text and i need to add a link in menu too in pim section  in oragehrm?Is it possible?I tried by adding new page like this.

```
Path : symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/modules/pim/actions

viewtestDetailsAction.class.php
class viewMyDetails extends basePimAction {

    private $userService;

    /**
     * @param sfForm $form
     * @return
     */
    public function setForm(sfForm $form) {
        if (is_null($this->form)) {
            $this->form = $form;
        }
    }

     /**
     * Get ConfigService
     * @return ConfigService
     */
    public function getConfigService() {
        if (is_null($this->configService)) {
            $this->configService = new ConfigService();
        }
        return $this->configService;
    }

    public function execute($request) {

    } 



    protected function viewMyDetails() {


                $this->redirect('pim/viewtestDetails');




    }

}
symfony/plugins/orangehrmPimPlugin/modules/pim/templates
viewtestDetails.php
<?php

echo "teset";

?>
```

Am i doing wrong?or what to do step by step to add simple page in pim section

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late to answer your question. What you have done is correct except for 2 small mistakes.

1. Name of your action class should end with `Action` suffix. For eg: your `viewMyDetails` action class should be renamed to `viewMyDetailsAction` .
2. Name of your success file should also followed by `Success` suffix. **And also most importantly it should match your action name too!** Therefore your success should be named as `viewMyDetailsSuccess` in this case.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I see you redirect the request to another action. It is better if you can debug this issue by looking into the `../symfony/log/orangehrm.log` further.